# How to dynamically load a file on a specific line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, modernizr

I created this script for a `core.js` file for my client's website and I want to dynamically load a few javascript libraries from that `core.js` file. However, javascript libraries require that you load that library *first*, then use the rest of your script, because you have to define your libraries object before calling it, doh. So I have this very simple script to dynamically load a file, but I want to know if there's a method to make sure that it loads it in priority ahead of the `core.js` file. Here's the current script:

```
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", "http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js");
    if(typeof script != "undefined") {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( script );
    }
})();
```

And in the debugger, you see:

[image]

Of course, it's going to load the dynamic file ahead of the core file, but I was wondering if there was a way to specify the line on the document for which to load the `modernizr` file? Otherwise, I can't use Modernizr, even though I have loaded it.

Obviously, I can't use jQuery, because I want to load that, too.

Comment: Does swapping those two lines around work? In other words, load modernizr before loading the blurred out line?

Comment: appendChild appends the script to the bottom of the head section, just run the functions in the right order and it appends the scripts in the right order, or use prepend to prepend the scripts instead.

Comment: @robbrit Well, the blurred out javascript file (which was done so upon request), is the javascript that actually loads the modernizr file, so I can't just swap them out. And adeneo, are you saying that I can use Modernizr and jQuery using my method as it is currently? In that same file? Because from my experience you have to load those *first*, then use it.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't use a `load` event listener (like `script.onload` or `script.addEventListener("load", ...)`) and run your library-dependent code in that event listener function?

Comment: So, `script.onload = function() { // library dependant code };` That'll work?

Comment: @ModernDesigner Absolutely. If you have multiple dependencies, just increment a counter after each one loads and fire your dependent code once the count reaches some desired value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can respond to the loading of a dynamically-loaded JavaScript resource (or any resource, for that matter -- image, iframe, video, etc.) with a `load` event listener. The easiest way to do it here would be:

```
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    ...
    script.onload = function() {
        // this will run later, when the script loads
        // in this function you can safely use Modernizr
    }
})();
```